# When window.document.baseURI be "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend

I always saw in the developer tool that both the entities(baseURI and URL) show the same URL, which is shown in the address bar most of the time. These are the properties of `window.document` object. So when is the situation that base URI property is "undefined"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do different things.

For what's in the address bar, you typically want [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

The [`baseURI` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) of nodes, on the other hand, is used as the base for resolving relative URLs within that node, for example the `src` of an image or `href` of a link. The `baseURI` can be changed by adding a [`<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

I have found no situations where `baseURI` is `undefined`. Even in a document created through [`document.implementation.createDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument), it is just inherited from the current `document`. Adding an empty `<base>` element has no effect. Assigning `undefined` to `baseURI` is simply ignored.

Comment: if no base tag is defined, so these properties are set by browser right?

Comment: Yes, the default base URI is the URI of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @Thomas. The IE11 (or lower) does not support `baseURI` property thus it will always be undefined.